# What is object nodelist

Tags: html

```
"[object NodeList]"
```

What is represented by the above in javascript?

I am firing the onkeypress event on a textbox, which depends over the value returned by various id of related radio buttons. When I fire the alert over the id, I get the above in the alert box.

Answer (score 2):

`[object NodeList]`, `object` means it is an object, `NodeList` is the interface the object implements. So it means it is a [NodeList](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodelist.asp) object.

Comment: Still its not clear to me. I have read the link but its objective is not clear to me.

Comment: So what is the unclean place?